# Changing clustermanager item icon in android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-utils

I have a google maps in my android app. It is full of markers, it clusters the markers... in a few words, a fully usable map.

What i want to do it's simple. When user tap on clusterItem, I want to change the icon to a selected one. (simply, same marker but with different color).

How I am using a lot of markers on screen, It's imposible to clean the map and add the markers everytime a mark is clicked.

So:

```
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem myItem) {
        if (oldItemSelected != null) {
            mClusterManager.removeItem(oldItemSelected);
            oldItemSelected.setItemAsNotSelected();
            mClusterManager.addItem(oldItemSelected);
        }

        mClusterManager.removeItem(myItem);
        myItem.setItemAsSelected();
        mClusterManager.addItem(myItem);
        mClusterManager.cluster();

        oldItemSelected = myItem;
        return true;
    }
});
```

The idea is to remove the item clicked from the map, set it to "selected", add the new item and refresh the map with .cluster method.

What happens: The item doesn't change, sometimes the item is "duplicated" and the selected is behind the "normal" item.

This is how I set up cluster manager:

```
mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, map);
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyItemRenderer());
mClusterManager.setAlgorithm(new GridBasedAlgorithm<MyItem>());
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
```

And this is the item renderer:

```
private class MyItemRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {
    public MyItemRenderer() {
        super(getApplicationContext(), map, mClusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem myItem, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        markerOptions.title(myItem.getName());
        markerOptions.snippet(myItem.getAddress());
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(myItem.getIcon()));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize() > 1;
    }

    public Marker getMarker(MyItem item) {
        return super.getMarker(item);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this without having to re-paint every item in the map?

```
public class MyItem extends DefaultClusterRenderer<WifiSpotItem> {

    private HashMap<Integer, Marker> markerWifiSpots = new HashMap<>();

    public MyItem(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<WifiSpotItem> mClusterManager) {
        super(context, map, mClusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(WifiSpotItem wifiSpotItem, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

        if (markerOptions != null && wifiSpotItem != null) {
            markerOptions.title(wifiSpotItem.getName() != null ? wifiSpotItem.getName() : Constants.EMPTY_STRING);
            markerOptions.snippet(wifiSpotItem.getAddress() != null ? wifiSpotItem.getAddress() : Constants.EMPTY_STRING);
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(wifiSpotItem.getIcon()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(WifiSpotItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {
        markerWifiSpots.put(clusterItem.getId(), marker);
        super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize() > 4;
    }

    public Marker getMarker(WifiSpotItem item) {
        return super.getMarker(item);
    }

    public Marker getMarker(int id) {
        Marker item;
        if (markerWifiSpots != null) {
            item = markerWifiSpots.get(id);
        } else {
            item = null;
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your MyItem Class too for me to get clear idea about the problem. @Javier Sivianes

Comment: I have added it @vivek

Comment: hi! have you find any solution? if yes, please, post you answer. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Seems that render task ignores objects which have been already displayed on the screen. I tried to add new instance of `MyItem` object (copy of `onClusterItemClick` method argument) to the cluster manager and it works.

```
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<MyItem>() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(MyItem myItem) {
        ...
        mClusterManager.removeItem(myItem);
        MyItem copy = myItem.copy();
        copy.setItemAsSelected();
        mClusterManager.addItem(copy);
        mClusterManager.cluster();
        ...
    }
});
```